# We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context

Tags: support, status-bydesign, questions

Somtimes below a question body this text block is placed:

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution. Answers that don't explain anything will be deleted. See Good Subjective, Bad Subjective for more information.

[Here is an example.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/why-do-panelists-on-british-panel-shows-have-a-pen-and-paper-which-they-seem-to).

I think I understand what types of questions "attract" this banner: questions that are conducive to guessing or giving undocumented short answers that are hard to verify.

My question is: when and how is this banner added to a question? Can we help moderators by flagging questions that may need this text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those **secret super special awesome** powers the mods have.  I have been tacking it on to those questions mostly because I can already tell some users will try to answer them with a "its like X" and that's it.

Your example in particular was added shortly after the question appeared [as noted in the edit history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/2328/revisions) as I knew this was something that needed some kind of official source.

And you can absolutely help us by noting which questions you think need this banner by using the custom moderator flag message thingy.

It should be worth noting that adding this notice doesn't increase the minimum answer length but rather notify potential answers that we would like some sort of explanation other than a one liner with a link.

Comment: Ah, I knew it! The moderator's SSSAP! OK, thanks we'll keep our eyes open.

Comment: @GertArnold - help is always welcome!  Thanks.

Comment: So I flagged, but got [declined](http://movies.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/297). Never mind, but what's the best way to do this? Maybe refer to this answer when flagging?

Comment: @GertArnold Not sure who/why the decline happened, notice has been added regardless.  I think it's more of a case of who looks at it.  Another way to get just a general opinion on the matter is to pop into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room) and ping the mods.  We're usually always in there (one of us are, anyway).