# Is this question helpful?

Tags: discussion

The question [Why does Madhavan help his ex-wife in the first place?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2522/why-does-madhavan-help-his-ex-wife-in-the-first-place) seems like it has a pretty straight-forward answer, but not having seen the movie I'm not 100% certain.  It was an attempt at a SE blog, but it's rather lacking in any meaningful or intriguing information.  I really want to close it, but I can't bring myself to it because I don't know the movie.  What's everyone else's opinion on this question?  Is it good enough to stay open, or should it be closed?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I don't feel the need to police posts to the degree that we close ones that are not of sufficient quality (in our humble opinion).

This Q & A example is (presumably) accurate, but as you say it is not particularly interesting as an SE Blog.

I think it doesn't deserve closing, but also does not deserve any upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, good idea to discuss this. I'd rather have someone give a better answer if there is one. Closing blocks this remedy and doesn't really improve anything quality-wise.

TylerShads has this [beautiful banner](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/458/297) to beg for profound answers. Maybe we could introduce a banner inviting people to give a better answer if an answer is stuck at zero (or less) votes and we feel that someone could do a better job. The OP can always re-evaluate his acceptance vote.

Hard to decide when to apply such a banner, though. Maybe we should just be more stern in casting downvotes.

Comment: Unfortunately the banners are not configurable by moderators, we can just choose one of a few options.  You can always leave a comment if you think you know why a zero vote answer is not getting more attention.

Comment: Ah, too bad. I though creating a banner was part of the awesome moderator powers.